# how to save images on cms?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

i have an old cms (classic asp) where for every image that the editor is upload i save 3 images (small,big and original).
  the size of the images are pre defined in the db (for each modul difrent size).

now in the new CMS (asp.net) that i build i think to save just the original and create images on demand with the right size?

did it's ok? i will get better flexibility but maybe it will be slower?

Answer (score 0):

Machines are super fast today, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't "help" them do their work :) Resizing images on deman is resource intensive. Think about situation where you have hundred concurent request that are resizing same image.

I think you should combine both solution. Use temporary cache for let's say, last hundred image requests. Optimization of this kind of solution depends primary on site traffic, so you should keep cache size as configuration option.